# How do i detect a WPFDataGrid row Data changed?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid`,and need to detect when a user has make changes to a row.I don't want to use `CellEditEnding` because whenever a row get focus and lost it without any inputs,this event get raised,in the other way i need to bind a bool property to each row that set to true when the row got chgangd.

Comment: are you using Binding for binding ItemSource of DataGrid or just assigning it using equal operator

Comment: I'm binding a list to the `ItemSource` using `Binding`.

Comment: Then use two way binding for ItemsSource and Changes made on View will be reflected in it , and try to Shift the logic to ViewModel instead of Binding bool property here and then making changes according to that bool property in VM.

Comment: But how could i understand in the `ViewModel` witch Row of `ItemSource` had been changed?

Comment: Couldn't you just add TextChanged="tb_TextChanged" event to your xaml and handle it in code behind?

Comment: No,I'm not writing in the `Code Behind`.

Comment: What is that you want to do when the `row` is changed? What is depending on row changed event could be a not-so-good idea after all? We can try a different approach than that.

Comment: @  Clinton Ward :Because i'm using MVVM!

Comment: @ WPF-it : i need to insert a new row in the Database for each row witch had changed!(i don't want to update them,and don't want to add the rows witch haden't changes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code as an example, so you know the basic idea of how to trace if an item in your `ItemSource` had been changed (here only compared to the initial value only).

```
List<myItem> Items=new List<myItem>(); //your ItemSource



    class myItem:ObservableObject //an class implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface
    {
        string _inititemName;
        string _itemName;
        bool itemChanged; //here is your indicator

        myItem(string name)
        {
            _inititemName=itemName=name;
        }

        public string itemName
        {   
            get{return _itemName;}
            set
            {  
                _itemName=vlaue; 
                if (_itemName!=_inititemName) 
                   itemChanged=true; 
                else 
                   itemChanged=false;
                RaisePropertyChanged("itemName"); //or whatever the name of the method is that invoke OnPropertyChanged
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to change my Model and set `ItemChanged` in all properties there!

Comment: Because I want to Find a better Solution!

Comment: So what is your criteria for `better` solution? I'm afraid, if you don't want to change anything you have but to still achieve what you cannot at the moment, is impossible..

Comment: No.i just don't want to change every thing to achieve this!i let you know when i've finished:P

Comment: @raha, OK, i'm looking forward to it. Please bear in mind, my solution is just a direction of how to involve an indicator. Indeed you don't need to set `ItemChanged` in all your properties, as if you have a lot properties, you can compare all your properties with the original value in the `get` block of `ItemChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the properties of your item class set a boolean update flag when they are modified

e.g.

```
public class MyGridItem
{
    public MyGridItem(string Name)
    { 
        this.Name = Name;
        Updated = false;
    }

    public bool Updated {get; private set;}

    private string _Name = null;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { 
                if (!_Name.Equals( value ))
                {
                    _Name = value;
                    Updated = true
                 }
            }
    }
}
```